# Formatting Powershell command line in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I can't seem to get this correct. Maybe fresh eyes?

This command works in a non-elevated Powershell window to change the last modified date of a file:

```
 (get-item "C:\users\ron\nwfundpositions.csv").lastwritetime=("16 Jun 2023 18:00:00")
```

[image]

I am trying to run the same command from VBA:

```
strCommand = "powershell " & PSline
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
```

In the code above, I have constructed `strCommand` to produce either:

```
powershell `"(get-item C:\Users\ron\NWFundPositions.csv.lastwritetime=(`"16 Jun 2023 18:00`")
```

or

```
powershell `"(get-item C:\Users\ron\NWFundPositions.csv.lastwritetime=(`"16 Jun 2023 18:00`")`"
```

In both cases, StdErr returns a message that there is a `Missing closing parenthesis ')' in expression`

[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: `...NWFundPositions.csv.lastwritetime` missing a parens I think.

Comment: In both your examples you’ve got 2 open braces and only one closing… e.g. ```powershell `"(get-item C:\Users\ron\NWFundPositions.csv.lastwritetime=(`"16 Jun 2023 18:00`")``` one opening before the ```get-item```and a pair around the ```"16 Jun 2023 18:00`"```. Presumably you need one to close the whole ```get-item``` expression?

Comment: @mclayton Fixed missing ')' after file name, but still getting same error with `powershell (get-item C:\Users\ron\NWFundPositions.csv).lastwritetime=(`"16 Jun 2023 18:00`")` (and there are back-ticks before the quotes surrounding the dates, just not showing up in the comment.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print PSline` return, for reproducibility?

Comment: @BigBen I've been staring and continued to miss that. But after fixing it, still had same error message.

Comment: @BigBen After correcting that missing parenthesis: `(get-item C:\Users\ron\NWFundPositions.csv).lastwritetime=(\`"16 Jun 2023 18:00\`")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verbatim command line you pass to `WshShell.Exec()` must look like this:

```
powershell (Get-Item \"C:\users\ron\nwfundpositions.csv\").LastWriteTime=\"16 Jun 2023 18:00:00\"
```

- On its *command line*, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, requires `"` characters that are to be be preserved as part of a PowerShell command to execute to be escaped as `\"`; *unescaped* `"` chars. are removed during the initial command-line parsing.

  - `` `" `` only works *in PowerShell code*; if you need specify such an escaped `"` *on the command line* (not necessary here), you need to use `` `\" `` (sic).
- Everything after `powershell` is considered the value for the (implied) `-Command` parameter.<sup>[1]</sup> Since *no shell* is involved when calling via `WshShell.Exec()`, enclosing the command in `"..."` *overall* isn't strictly necessary in this case, though such enclosure *is* required if whitespace normalization must be prevented (multiple spaces turning into one).

---

Alternatively, you can use `'...'` quoting, given that your string values do not require expansion (interpolation), and omit the optional quoting around the file path:

```
powershell (Get-Item C:\users\ron\nwfundpositions.csv).LastWriteTime='16 Jun 2023 18:00:00'
```

If the string is constructed programmatically and there's a chance that the path contains *spaces* (or other PowerShell metacharacters), you do need to quote it; however, if you use `'...'` quoting, you must ensure that the file path doesn't itself contain `'` or, if it does, *double* the embedded `'`; Using `\"...\"` quoting is then the simpler alternative, given that file paths cannot contain `"` themselves.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the CLI of [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is a different executable, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh). It defaults to `-File`, so in order to pass *commands*, `-Command` (`-c`) must be specified *explicitly*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you multiple times!! I didn't realize the different escape character required for the Windows Powershell CLI and didn't think to try the single quote.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @RonRosenfeld; my pleasure. Yes, it isn't obvious that ``\"`` must be used (in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) you can also use `""`), but I presume this was done to align with other CLIs.

Comment: I just installed 7, but the VBA call is still going to 5.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, the CLI of v7+ is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI; additionally, you must use `-Command` (`-c`) explicitly.